# How to read all excel and csv formats using node

Tags: node.js, excel, mongodb, csv, mean-stack

I am working in building a project management tool,using MEAN(Mongodb,Expressjs,Angularjs,Nodejs) Stack.

I have a requirement in my project, where users will upload any kind of excel or csv format file and i need to parse each row from the file(excel|csv) and map it to my database model and save it has a mongodb document.I am trying to find an excel and csv parser library to accomplish my task.I also came accross [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx), it looks good but it doesnt support reading csv files.It will be really helpful if any one could suggest a node.js library that can read all kinds of excel and csv file formats efficiently.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At one point, I used [Node CSV](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv) https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv
to get the data inputted, it's really easy to use.  Most of my users were fine with just having the CSV format option.....but you could combine the functionality of each library depending on the file type entered.....